# Does anyone make dummy batteries for eTap AXS derailleurs?

Tags: derailleur, battery

I just got a new Specialized Roubaix Expert with SRAM parts. I discovered that lengthy car rides drain the batteries because the derailleurs are triggered into activity by motion.

Solution? Take the batteries off for long travel. Check.

The problem is, the place where the batteries seat in the derailleurs has two tiny spring-loaded prongs that could get fouled with road dust, oil, and other contaminants—or worse, snapped off by some misadventure—over long rides on an outside bike rack.

A perfect solution to this would be a plastic or nylon "dummy" battery that could just be snapped into place for the ride. Does anybody know of such a solution? I suppose plastic wrap and rubber bands could work, but geez, what a [Red Green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Red_Green_Show) kind of fix that would be!

**PLEASE NOTE: I'm not looking for replacement batteries or any standard item. I've been all over the Web and checked out SRAM and other websites for a solution, to no avail.**

### UPDATE

I went to a bike shop (not where I bought the bike) and, thanks to Gary's and Nanobis's enlightening me as to the name of this item, I was able to ask for precisely what I needed: a *battery block* for the SRAM AXS derailleurs. Not only that, but they just *gave* them to me. No charge. Life is good.

[image: Derailleur battery attached]

[image: Derailleur battery detached showing springs]

Comment: This seems like a really good use case for a 3D printed solution.

Comment: My 2c but they look robust to me, I wouldn't bother myself, or just wrap a rag around them whenever you drive through an oil storm. Keep it simple ‍♂️. I understand that not everyone is the same however, I wouldn't be critical of anyone looking to protect it .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Talk to the bike shop where you got the bike.  The bike should have come with this as part of a kit that includes the charger and 2 little plastic battery protectors. The color is red, of course. There is one part that snaps in the battery cage on the bike and another that snaps onto the battery when you take it out for storage.  I bought a gravel bike last year with SRAM Rival eTap AXS Rear Derailleur.  I use this little adapter thingy each time I transport the bike.  The only real problem is keeping track where I last put it - I can live with that :-)

Here is a picture of the plastic part to snap on to the battery when off the bike:

https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/bike-frame-parts/sram-axs-battery-terminal-cover/p/36756/

Here is a picture of the "SRAM eTap Derailleur Battery Block".  This is the part that snaps into your derailleur when travelling:

https://sportfactoryproshop.com/sram-etap-battery-block/

One more edit:  here is a pic of what it looks like installed:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Gary. I do have the battery protectors but not the ones for the cages on the bike. If you can provide a link to those, I'll award you the checkmark.

Comment: @Robusto ahh ok.  It seems finding these online is a little tricky.  Maybe sold out on some stores?  I had good luck searching for SRAM eTap Derailleur Battery Block.  I'd still check with the store where you got the bike.  They probably have a way to get it.

Comment: This is the droid you're looking for. Your derailleur should have come with the appropriate cover. If it didn't, talk to the person who sold it to you. That said, AXS derailleurs we're first introduced in the MTB space and a little bit of road spray is unlikely to harm it. I have plenty of grit in mine from regular riding in PNW slop. Finally, AFAIK, the only movement that wakes the derailleur is chain movement. If your chain is moving enough to wake and drain your derailleur, you probably want to secure your cranks while in transit, more than anything.

Comment: Thanks, Gary, knowing what to call these things proved essential.  I just went to a bike store that sold SRAM and got them to give me a couple of these battery blocks, no charge!

Answer (score 14):

I've never handled one of these, but it looks like you could take the battery off, put a small piece of electrical tape over the contacts, and put it back on.

If you have to cut the tape in a fiddly way so it fits, fold one edge over and it will peel off to use again a few times.

You could of course fit tape semi-permanently to a second battery, treating it as a dummy until you need it.

It's not clear from the pictures where the seal is - I assume there is one. But 3d printing such a shape wouldn't be hard for someone with one to hand and a 3d printer. Getting a 3d-printed cover to seal properly would be the hard part.

Comment: There are already models for 3d printing these, e.g. https://www.printables.com/model/497906-sram-etapaxs-cover-for-battery-block. To seal properly you would probably need to glue a thin layer of soft rubber seal on the inner side.

Comment: No need for *electrical* tape. Any tape that's not specifically conductive will do. Like old cheap tesa. Heck, you could even just use a sticky note in a pinch.

Comment: No need for tape or 3d printing. Just insert a clearly marked dead battery while the bike is being transported.

Comment: Thanks, good answer and great thinking. I think I will try this, but with the added feature of putting paper on the tape where it would face the electrical contacts so that no adhesive is deposited on the contacts themselves.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica I like electrical tape for this sort of thing because it comes off cleanly without tearing - and even if you don't use it for electrical stuff it's worth having in a bike workshop, e.g. for finishing bar tape (under the supplied finishing tape if you want the look, because that's never long enough and rarely stretchy enough)

Comment: @Marjan I'm not surprised.  I was going to look on thingiverse and grabcad, but I've been out riding

Comment: I would cover the exposed area in lunch wrap / glad wrap / sarin wrap as a temporary protection.  It should be good enough to reuse on the trip home too.

Comment: This solution is great, but instead of using tape you could just place a piece of paper or thin plastic between the battery & the housing, to impede electrical contact. Something as simple as the wrapping of granola bars or anything really can work here, just avoid anything too thick as mating the battery to the housing might become difficult or impossible.

Answer (score 3):

The part your looking for is a battery mount cover for eTap / AXS / Eagle AXS
Manufacturer (SRAM) Number: 11.7618.008.000
Most of them are appear out of stock but I have found this other eBay listing [battery block](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/276018795577)

I know this isn't what your wanting, but these battery covers/protectors exist and can add a pop of colour to the bike.

[Axs battery protector](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/385780348176) looks like theres a suprisingly big market for them as the official SRAM ones are just black.

Comment: Thanks, Nanobis, knowing what to call these solved the problem. I just went to a bike store that sold SRAM and got them to *give me* a couple of these battery blocks! No charge!

Answer (score -1):

Going to assume these are like the assioma pedals. Log into the Bluetooth application and turn the device to travel mode.

Comment: Can you confirm that “travel mode” (or something similar) exists for this device?

Comment: Welcome to the site - this is a great point, that addresses the underlying need, without specifically answering the question as-written.   If someone with the software can explore it for "travel mode" that would be ideal.

Comment: https://www.sram.com/en/life/stories/all-about-sram-axs-batteries does not mention travel mode, just about removing batteries and clipping covers to bike and battery.

Comment: https://www.sram.com/en/life/stories/10_Things_You_Might_Not_Know_About_eTap_AXS    also does not mention any kind of travel mode.   This might not exist on Sram

Comment: https://cycling.favero.com/en/faq  clearly describes their travel mode, and exiting requires the charger to wake up the pedals.   Looks like SRAM does not offer this functionality at this time.

Comment: Even SRAM [themselves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19xfwgGykuw) just recommend taking off these covers and no mention of a _travel mode_ on their electronic groupsets, and that's a fairly recent video (mid 2023). By the way, when using the Assioma pedal's travel mode, don't forget to bring the charger because that is the only way to wake them up, again.